# Syntax colors for tab; line return; body of text (VIM, .txt)

Tags: text, vim, syntax, colors, highlight

How to create a highlight syntax colorscheme for .txt, in vim, to:

- between 2 lines returns: change the color of subsequent, ex:

  body of text red
  (empty line)
  (empty line)
  body of text blue
- "stabilo" highlight paragraph if 0 tab (ideally with the color of body of text)
- bold paragraph if 1 tab (15 spaces for me)
- normal paragraph if 2 tabs (30 spaces)
- italic paragraph if 3 tabs (45 spaces)

I have 0 knowledge in code/vim/computers, I just want to write text. I have already looked into vimhelp syntax, neovimdoc usr44, etc...

Edit:
The code below is an attempt for the tab syntax.
It does not work yet but some directions would be appreciated.
I cannot find ideas for the 2 empty lines = change color.
p.s.: if any website exist that give direct answers, please let me know

```
"Set background and reset existing colours
set background=dark
hi clear
if exists("syntax_on")
  syntax reset
endif

let g:colors_name="mindmap"
                              
syntax match xLevel1 /.*/
syntax match xLevel2 /\t.*/
syntax match xLevel3 /\t\t.*/
syntax match xLevel4 /\t\t\t.*/
syntax match xLevel5 /\t\t\t\t.*/
syntax region x1 start=/\n\n/ end=/\n\n/ 

hi xLevel1     guifg=#FFFFFF  gui=undercurl  ctermfg=15     cterm=undercurl
hi xLevel2     guifg=#FFFFFF  gui=bold       ctermfg=15     cterm=bold
hi xLevel3     guifg=#FFFFFF  gui=NONE       ctermfg=15     cterm=NONE
hi xLevel4     guifg=#FFFFFF  gui=italic                    
hi xLevel5     guifg=#FFFFFF  gui=italic
```

Comment: "I have already looked into vimhelp syntax, neovimdoc usr44, etc..." That is where your answer is. You should read it, try something, and then come back with an actual programming question.

Comment: I don't even know where to start. Where to put the file. How to name it. It is chinese for me. I'm 64. I'm just asking for help. If it is not the correct website to ask, please let me know one?

Comment: Well… one can learn to code at any age. See if there is some kind of computer club or maker space in your area, where you could find people ready to volunteer some of their time. Case in point, since you don't know anything about the topic at hand, explaining you how to reach your goal requires a lot of previous knowledge that you don't have so it would take significantly more words than there are in the documentation you mentioned. Good luck.

Comment: I am trying sir; cf edit.